# Horizontal scroll in phonegap android project

Tags: android, cordova, horizontal-scrolling

I'm developing an app in phonegap for android and iphone. I want to implement a horizontal scroll in the top menu, with common css rules it's working in iPhone but not in android.

My html menu looks like a common list type with ul and li.

Do you know how I could accomplish this? iScoll is not working for me and I would like to avoid jquery mobile since it's too heavy to implement only this functionality. If someone knows how jquery mobile accomplishes this and could extract only that part of code it would be great, or someone found a better way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

iScroll is a way to provide horizontal and vertical scrolling in WebKit browsers.

EDIT: I see you have tried iScroll. What about it didn't work for you? It was the only solution I could find.

Comment: It just didn't work with iscroll, it worked in the computer browser but not in the device.
I solved it by changing the screen design so it doesn't need the scroll, thanks anyway

Comment: Darry, having some issues using iscroll in phonegap with requirejs. Would it be possible to have some pointers to a solution...I will attach some code below...

Answer (score 0):

My try at iscroll in phonegap using requirejs.

```
require(['jquery','views/test','iscroll','domready','index'],function($,TestView,iScroll,domReady){         
    new TestView;  

    var menu_iscroll;

    domReady(function() {
    alert("entered domready for creating iscroll");
    menu_iscroll = new iScroll('hmenu',{ hScroll: true, vScroll: false, hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false  });           
    menu_iscroll.refresh();
    alert("finished iscroll refresh");
    });

});
```

this does not work for some reason. I have debugged with alert and the function is triggered after dom is ready ...but the hmenu is still just a normal list...without any horizontal rendering...